# how to convert firebase data snapshot to fullcalendar eventobject?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, fullcalendar

I'm trying to populate a fullCalendar with events that I have taken from Firebase.

The problem is the data taken from firebase isn't compatible with the event format used by fullCalendar.

It's always giving me the

> hastime is undefined

error. I searched and it said that something is wrong with the structure of the event, but I double-checked and the structure is fine.

The method I'm using is in the events function I'm using the callback to render events. It looks something like this:

```
events: ( start, end, timezone, callback ) => {
  this.db.getAppointments('id').subscribe(snapshot => callback([snapshot.val()]));
}
```

Here without the `'[]'`, `snapshot.val()` is an object containing multiple objects. So it's not compatible.

The value that I'm getting:

```
{71943808: {…}, 033808341: {…}}
```

and I don't need the keys because it will no longer satisfy the structure of the fullCalendar. fullCalendar wants an array of objects which is why there is another callback that I can implement in fullCalendar:

```
eventDataTransform:(eventData)=>{
    console.log(eventData);
    let arrayOfApp=[];

    Object.keys(eventData).forEach( key => {
        console.log(key);
        console.log(eventData[key]);
        arrayOfApp.push(eventData[key]); 
    });

    return arrayOfApp;
}
```

I'm trying here to re-arange my data so my final returned data will be an array of objects, but it won't work - same error.

So now `arrayofApp` looks something like this:

```
[
  {end: "2017-11-26T08:02:00", start: "2017-11-26T08:01:00", title: "number"},
  {end: "2017-11-28T08:02:00", start: "2017-11-28T08:01:00", title: "number"}
]
```

and still it's giving me

> hastime is undefined

Can anyone help?

Comment: As per the docs https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/eventDataTransform/, eventDataTransform works on a _single event object at a time_, not the whole dataset. So when you return an array from it, fullCalendar expects a single object. But it's already too late for this callback to help - you need to change your `this.db.getAppointments('id').subscribe(snapshot => callback([snapshot.val()]));` to return an array in the format fullCalendar understands. There is no other way. I don't know what that code is doing unfortunately (I don't know Firebase) so I can't help with that.

Comment: thank you so much for your time i solved my problem minutes after i posted my question the trick was not to use the eventDataTransform method instead i created my own function that returns an the array and giving it back to the callback and it works fine .

Comment: but now i have another problem after posting my new event the fullcalendar isnt refreshed how can i do that with angular2

Comment: It's hard to be specific because obviously I can't see your code to see what you're doing, and whether you're doing anything wrong. But in general if you create a new event you can either add it to the calendar immediately client-side (as well as posting to the db) using the renderEvent method (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/), or you can force a manual refresh of calendar data from the server by calling the refetchEvents method
(https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/refetchEvents/), which should then fetch the latest event array from the db including the new event